# Persistent HTTP Connection in J2me

Tags: java-me, httpconnection

I am creating Java ME Application, its frequently get data from server with 5 minute gap. Can I use persistent HTTP connection for each request?

Can I use same connection for each request?

Comment: added the java tag - it does deal with java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, sure you can.

However, if you are going to have a server that will be handling requests from a large number of devices, you would probably NOT want persistent connections.

Comment: thanks for your replay,please explain how can i handle in the server and client.

Comment: You've shown us absolutely no code. Old, but pretty good docs on this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html

Comment: I have used wrong tag for posting the question.Creating mobile application in Java ME,using this how can I use  persist HTTP connection for each 5 minutes interval.please give some idea.

Comment: I .. just answered that. Those docs are applicable to Java ME as well (for the most part)

Comment: You might find this useful too: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_Http_and_Https_in_Java_ME

Comment: If you are going to have 5 minutes of silence between the requests, I believe there will be no performance saving from keeping the connection alive - in fact the opposite. Personally I would recommend closing the connection in between.

Comment: Not necessarily; if there is enormous overhead in making the connection again (e.g. the server has to connect to multiple databases), it might be better to keep it persistent, but, in most cases, I would say no persistence too.